# Font quality under 12.1 on Linux

Tags: fonts, linux

I have an issue with MMA 12.1 under Linux, specifically, xubuntu 18.04.4, and even more specifically, font rendering.

A semi-random plot, in this case,

```
Plot[Sin[x Cos[x]], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]},
ColorFunction->ColorData["SolarColors"],
BaseStyle->{FontFamily->"Helvetica", 10}
]
```

under 12.1 exported to pdf, then converted to png (using pdftocairo) looks like
[image]

The same plot under 12.0 looks like 
[image]

Incidentally, there's no difference in quality whether I export to PDF, then convert, or whether I `Export[file, graphic, "PNG"]`.

Observe the difference in the quality in fonts under 12.1. I'm less worried about the difference in graticules, since they should be fixable.

Same results using any of the 2D & 3D plotting functions: 12.0 results in crisp vector fonts whereas 12.1 results in dithered unreadable messes.

Searching on StackExchange has not apparently revealed a fix, but I'd certainly appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

In any case, until such a fix can be found, I'm back to 12.0.

Comment: Can you provide the code to generate the graphics?

Comment: Very likely, the contents of the PDF were already rasterized.

Comment: @Szabolcs: you're likely right. On closer inspection, there's something funky with the plotted line in the 12.1 image.

Comment: @Szabolcs I had the same problem last month.  Once the ColorFunction is included in line (changing with coordinates), the output PDF will be rasterized, and the texts inside are not selectable.

Comment: @Pei-Xin Shen: were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: I'm more surprised by 12.0 producing vector output, actually. You can increase the `ImageResolution` when exporting to get better quality.

Comment: @dwa No elegant solution as far as I can see.... What I did is to make two copies of plots, the colorful one is set to `AxesStyle -> Transparent`, another one is set to `PlotStyle -> Transparent`, and use Overlay to combine them...

Comment: As an FYI, I tested the 12.1.1 release in the hope of a fix.  This is still broken.