# Graphics3D font issue in Mathematica 12.1 (Linux )

Tags: graphics3d, fonts

I just upgraded to Mathematica 12.1 from 11.3, and text in 3D graphics is now very ugly (but text in 2D graphics looks fine); here's an example:
[image: screenshot]
Adding `Antialiasing->True` doesn't make any difference.  Any ideas on what the issue might be?  (Exported images are what I really care about, and they have the same problem.)

Comment: I have a similar issue with fonts under 12.1 on Linux here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220051/font-quality-under-12-1-on-linux.  I downgraded to 12.0.

Comment: Thanks @dwa, downgrading to 12.0 fixed my issue as well.